# How to send Pushnotification from Parse.com using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using this SDK for Parse.com
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk
This is not working for me while sending Push notifications using

```
$query= ParseInstallation::query();
$query->where('deviceType', 'ios');
parsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $query,
  "data" => array(
    "alert" => "Hello Hello !"
  )
));
```

**Getting This:** Fatal error: Call to undefined method ParseInstallation::query() in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I am using to send a push notification and it works perfectly. Make sure you've setup in the dashboard the ability to send push notifications from a client.

```
$notification = "Your notification!";
$query = ParseInstallation::query();
$query->equalTo("deviceType", "ios");

$data = array("alert" => $notification);

ParsePush::send(array(
  "where" => $query,
  "data" => $data
));
```

Comment: I am also using same code but Getting This: Fatal error: Call to undefined method ParseInstallation::query() in